# Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

I have come across this Error I've not seen before:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters
```

Referring to the following code (have simplified the function for ease of reading):

```
if ($frm->isValid($this->_getAllParams()) || !count($frm->getMessages())) //error points to this line of an array
                {
                    //set session with id of user
                    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('rg');
                    $session->userid = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
                    //update the user
                    $mdl->createClient($this->_getAllParams());
                    //add to log - do in model
                    $this->_redirect('/.../...');
                }
```

## 6 C:\xampp\htdocs\portal-gep-2\library\Null\Validate\Db\NoRecordExists.php(7): Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists->isValid('7505020152089')

```
class Null_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists extends Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists
{
    public function isValid($value)
    {
       $response = parent::isValid($value);//this line
       if(!$response){
           $this->_messages =
                array(self::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND=> "Please correct this error before continuing <a href='/data-control/idnum/id/$value'>Correct Issue</a>");
       }
       return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that mention line ? Because its a SQL error and I don't think any SQL statement is getting fired on that line.

Comment: I guess you use a validator like `Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists` or other, I think this is where you should look.

Comment: I edited my question take a look

Comment: How did you declare your validator and element which uses it?

Comment: Consider closing this question, too specific.

Answer (score 0):

The form in question has a constructor of the form:

```
public function __construct($formState = 'createlocal', $currentTask = null)
```

based on whether the form is updating an existing record or a new record it will make use of a custom validator: `Null_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists`.

In the specific case you talk of the form is using a `Db_NoRecordExists` on an existing record and hence we whould like to exclude a specific record (the current one) using one of the constructor parameters in this case: `$currentTask`.

`$currenctTask` may be an array and the validator may make use of an array variable while ensuring the Record does not exist (in the where clause). However the variable is not parsed when initially constucting the form.

Hence check that `$currentTask` contains what it needs to contain. The error is of your own making.